# How can I return value from bool function with formal parameters?

Tags: c++

```
int Solve(double& root1,double& root2) //this is function in the class Eq2
{
    int discrimant = b*b - 4*a*c;
    if(discriminant<0)
    return false;
    else if(discriminant>0)
    {
    root1 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a);
    root2 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a);
    return root1;    //must return root1 and root2
    }
}

int main()
{
Eq2 eq1(1, -5, 6);   //discriminant=1,root1=2,root2=3
Eq2 eq2(1, -6, 8);   //discriminant=4,root1=2,root2=4
Eq2 eq3(1, 2, 3);
Eq2 eq4(0, 0, 0);

double root1, root2;
Eq2 eqq[4] = { eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4 };
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    eqq[i].print();
}
cout << "The roots of the equation are:"<<eq1.Solve(root1,root2);   //here 
i call the function

system("pause");
return 0; 
}
```

I made the function int and it is working but i can ouput just 1 root.I need to return root1 and root2.Thank you everyone for your help!I'm still in the beginning and i have a lot to learn.

Comment: Please format your code to be proper C++ code

Comment: Now, instead of declaring `bool` as a return value you should return `int`. In other words, `bool Solve(int &root1,int&root2)` should be `int Solve(int &root1,int&root2)`. Or if your function is used only for setting values `root1` and `root2`, then I suppose no return value is needed. In that case `void Solve(int &root1,int&root2)` should be the signature

Comment: "return" is an ambiguous term in this case. Since root1 and root2 are passed by reference, just by assigning their values you are providing the correct values to the caller. What you should return is true. And you should check if the discriminant is lower than 0 and return false in that case.

Comment: @NutCracker I believe that bool is a nice return value, since tha function can "fail" to compute the roots.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the code that calls `Solve`.

Comment: This helped thank you.But i can only return one root but the task is to return both values.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana The `bool` might be a nice return value with adding the appropriate checks whether computation fails or not. ;-)

Comment: @CostantinoGrana I agree but i think OP first needs to understand what are references used for, and, furthermore, OP didn't clarify what he want exactly

Comment: @Amanda but you _are_ alread "returning" `root1` and `root2` because these paremeters are passed by reference.

Comment: 1. You can return as many values as you like with the appropriate bundling. E.g. `std::pair<int, int>` could do the job. 2. Reference parameters can be a "kind of return" as well.

Comment: @Scheff we'll never know ;)

Comment: @NutCracker - sqrt() returns a double! shouldn't all the "int"s and the "bool" be "double"s?

Comment: @Marichyasana agree there is many space for improvement in this code but, as i said, first version wasn't even formatted properly, there was no semicolons so I think we need to go one step at the time.

Comment: @Scheff ofc. ty :) Anyway, i will sum up all the comments in one answer so let me know if i missed sth

Comment: Yes the roots must be double .

Comment: I need to return both roots. When i write return x1,x2 the output is just the one root .

Comment: @Amanda Please read all comments and the answer! Don't try to "guess" the syntax. Comma is a C++ operator which you don't want to use. Try to understand what that & means in the parameters.

Comment: @Amanda Thank you for updating your code, now the question is clear and there are some pretty good ansers. But the formatting of your code is still very poor. Google "C++ indentation style".

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer:

While writing my own MCVE, OP edited the question. Hence, my identifiers are a little bit different. I hope this will not cause confusion...

[Discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) is such a special word, that I immediately remembered that I learnt it in math. The rest was lost but immediately refreshed from Wikipedia and what else google found.

The actual issue of OP seems to be to understand how [reference parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) can be used to return values from functions without using (or additionally to) `return`. This is IMHO already covered in the other answers.

Hence, I focused on demonstrating this in action.

Thereby, I noticed some additional issues which should be considered.

1. [`std::sqrt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) should be called with value ≥0 only.

> If the argument is less than -0, FE_INVALID is raised and NaN is returned.

2. Division by 0 should be checked.
3. (Due to hint of my colleague who is Dipl.-Math.) With very small values, the results of division become non-trustable.

It's in general a bad idea to compare floating point values with constants due to the usual rounding issues. Hence, I introduce an `eps` – an epsilon value to compensate at little bit.

Sample code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

struct Quad {
  double a, b, c;
  Quad(double a, double b, double c): a(a), b(b), c(c) { }
  Quad(const Quad&) = default;
  Quad& operator=(const Quad&) = default;
  ~Quad() = default;

  bool solve(double &root1, double &root2) const;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Quad &quad)
{
  return out << quad.a << "x² + " << quad.b << "x + " << quad.c;
}

static double eps = 1E-10;

/* tries to solve the roots of this quadratic function.
 *
 * return: true (solution exists)
 *         root1 and root2 contain results
 *         false (no solution)
 *         root1 and root2 are indeterminate (unchanged)
 */
bool Quad::solve(double &root1, double &root2) const
{
  double discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
  if (discriminant < 0.0) return false; // square root of a negative!
  if (std::abs(a) < eps) return false; // division by 0! (or close to 0)
  root1 = (-b - std::sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
  root2 = (-b + std::sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
  return true;
}

int main()
{
  double root1, root2; // declared but not yet initialized
  Quad quad1(-1, 0, 1); // two solutions
  std::cout << "Roots for " << quad1 << ": ";
  if (!quad1.solve(root1, root2)) std::cout << "none\n";
  else std::cout << root1 << ", " << root2 << '\n';
  Quad quad2(1, -4, 4); // one solution
  std::cout << "Roots for " << quad2 << ": ";
  if (!quad2.solve(root1, root2)) std::cout << "none\n";
  else std::cout << root1 << ", " << root2 << '\n';
  Quad quad3(1, 0, 2); // no solution
  std::cout << "Roots for " << quad3 << ": ";
  if (!quad3.solve(root1, root2)) std::cout << "none\n";
  else std::cout << root1 << ", " << root2 << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Roots for -1x² + 0x + 1: 1, -1
Roots for 1x² + -4x + 4: 2, 2
Roots for 1x² + 0x + 2: none
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6af78ca68f26b9a1)</kbd>

The trick is that `Quad::solve()` returns `true` or `false` (as documented) and updates the variables `root1` and `root2` in the former case but not in the latter.

In a less compact form written:

```
  bool valid = quad1.solve(root1, root2);
  if (valid) { // root1, root2 updated
    std::cout << root1 << ", " << root2 << '\n';
  } else { // no result computed -> root1, root2 not updated
    std::cout << "none\n";
  }
```

I took the sample values from this [German site](https://de.serlo.org/mathe/terme-gleichungen/gleichungen/quadratische-gleichungen/diskriminante-1513).

[image: Samples from de.serlo.org]

Comment: Nice, I didn't even consider the "`a` close to 0" case. Shows that there are always more to consider. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is some arguing over what the return type should be, I would argue that `int` is better than `bool` because there are three different return scenarios that you might want to signal (no root, a single root, and two roots). You can argue that the latter two can be distinguished by doing a `root1 == root2` comparison in the caller, but if you have to return a success value, why not make it able to express all the options.

So my answer would be something like this:

```
int Solve(double& root1, double& root2)
{
    int discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (discriminant < 0)  // No roots
        return 0;
    if (discriminant == 0)  // One root
    {
        root1 = (-b) / (2 * a);
        root2 = root1;
        return 1;
    }
    // Two roots
    root1 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
    root2 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
    return 2;
}

int main()
{
    Eq2 eq1(1, -5, 6);   //discriminant=1,root1=2,root2=3
    Eq2 eq2(1, -6, 8);   //discriminant=4,root1=2,root2=4
    Eq2 eq3(1, 2, 3);
    Eq2 eq4(0, 0, 0);

    double root1, root2;
    Eq2 eqq[4] = { eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        eqq[i].print();
    }

    int numRoots = eq1.Solve(root1, root2);

    switch (numRoots) {
    case 0:
        cout << "The the equation has no roots" << endl;
        break;
    case 1:
        cout << "The the equation has one root: " << root1 << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "The the equation has two roots: " << root1 << ", " << root2 << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Error: This should be impossible" << endl;
        break;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments: "return" is an ambiguous term in this case. You want the caller to be able to obtain the roots of your second degree equation.

Since root1 and root2 are passed by reference, just by assigning their values you are providing the correct values to the caller. What you should return is true. And you should check if the discriminant is lower than 0 and return false in that case.

As @Marichyasana suggested, probably all `int`s should become `double`s.

```
bool Solve(double& root1, double& root2)
{
    int discrimant = b*b - 4*a*c;
    if (discriminant < 0)
        return false;
    root1 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a);
    root2 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will sum up all the suggestions from the comments in one answer:

- if you pass non-const references as an arguments to the function, you can update their values and it will remain updated in the code that initially called that function
- you should probably consider using `double`s instead `int`s because `sqrt` function returns `double`
- you should also consider adding some checks if the calculation fails so you can return `false` in that case or `true` otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Signature is strange, returning list of root seems more appropriate:

```
std::vector<double> SolveEq2(double a, double b, double c)
{
    if (a == 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Not equation of 2nd degree");
    }
    auto discriminant = b*b - 4*a*c;

    if (discriminant < 0) {
        return {}; // No roots;
    }
    else if (discriminant > 0)
    {
        auto sqrtDiscriminant = sqrt(discriminant);
        return {(-b - sqrtDiscriminant) / (2 * a),
                (-b + sqrtDiscriminant) / (2 * a)};
    } else { // == 0
        return {-b / (2 * a)};
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/7qtmFZ)